# How can I change this javascript hover to two separate clicks?

Tags: jquery, css, click, hover

I have seen other questions similar to mine, but I followed the advice of others and still cannot get this to work.

```
$("#TyPhoto").click(function(){
    $("#TyBio").show("slow");
    $("#TyPhoto").setAttribute("id", "#newTy");
    });
$("#newTy").click(function () {
    $("#TyBio").hide(1000);
    $("#newTy").setAttribute("id", "#TyPhoto");
    });
```

I am trying to show each biography text on a `click` and then `hide` it on the second click. The first click works, but the second one does not hide the text. The live site is located [here](http://2013.igem.org/Team%3aGeorgia_State/Team/members).

The CSS is just a `display:none` for #TyBio.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think elements are supposed to change IDs. Consider setting a CSS class.

Comment: When you do a direct event bind like that, you are binding to the element. The binding doesn't change when you change attributes of the element, because the event is already bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You could use the toggle method if all you're going to do is hide/show:

```
$("#TyPhoto").click(function(){   
    $("#TyBio").toggle("slow"); //or toggle(1000)
});
```

API docs : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

## Alternatives

### Method 1

You've got an image like this :

```
<img id="DafPhoto" class="insetshadow" src="" width="352" height="272">
```

And a div like this which contains the bio like this :

```
<div id="DafBio" style="display: none;">.</div>
```

So on every click is going to be unique if youre going to use IDs. Try changing the image tag to something like this :

```
<img class="insetshadow" data-bio="DafBio" src="" width="352" height="272">
```

(Added a `data-bio` attribute to it and removed the id)

Then change your clicks to this :

```
$(".insetshadow").click(function(){   
    var bioId = $(this).data("bio");
    $("#" + bioId).toggle("slow"); //or toggle(1000)
});
```

### Method 2

Or even simpler, you seem to have this kind of a structure :

```
<ul id="navlist">
 <li>
    <img class="insetshadow" >
 </li>
 <!--extra stuff-->
 <li>
    <img class="insetshadow" >
 </li>
</ul>

<span id="descriptblock" class="outshadow">
<div class="bio" id="TyBio"></div>
   <!--extra stuff-->
<div class="bio" id="DawnBio"></div>
</span>
```

Note that I've added extra classes to both. Remove the IDs and keep it this way. Now you could use index property to match the elements :

```
 $(".insetshadow").click(function(){   
        $(".bio").hide();
        var index= $(this).index();
        $(".bio:eq(" + index + ")").toggle("slow"); //or toggle(1000)
 });
```

## Edit

To add extra events to this :

```
 $(".insetshadow").on("click mouseover mouseout", function(){   
        //hide the rest 
        $(".bio").hide();
        var index= $(this).index();
        $(".bio:eq(" + index + ")").toggle("slow"); //or toggle(1000)
 });
```

Comment: Why query the DOM on every click?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Although true im sure `document.getElementById()` is damn fast. And its not in a loop or whatever so...

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realize that toggle worked that way.

Comment: Thanks again! I realize my code is not very well organized, and I'm learning that it's really important with larger projects. I really appreciate the tips!

Comment: I do have one more question. When I add the javascript you suggested, each photo clicked toggles the same bio every time. How can I make the bios match to their individual photos? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Since the images have no children, they had no index values beyond 0. Therefore I needed to use `.parent().index();` in order to take the index value for the bios. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Pack both in one click handler and just toggle a class to alternate between the two states.
This would come in handy when more actions need to be executed

```
$("#TyPhoto").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('toggled');

    if($this.hasClass('toggled')) {
        // ACTION ON TOGGLE ON
    } else {
        // ACTION ON TOGGLE OFF
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two mistakes here. First, the ID attribute doesn't include the #. So, in order to set the "newTy" id you should do

```
$("#TyPhoto").click(function(){
    $("#TyBio").show("slow");
    $("#TyPhoto").setAttribute("id", "newTy");
});
```

Second, I believe there's no newTy element on the beggining, so you cannot add listeners to it. You should delegate instead:

```
$(document).on("click","#newTy",function () {
    $("#TyBio").hide(1000);
    $("#newTy").setAttribute("id", "TyPhoto");
});
```

Yeah, I removed the # from TyPhoto too.